# What is difference between NSDictionary vs Dictionary in Swift?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift, nsdictionary

I'm learning Swift, and I can see `Dictionary` in it.
But there are lots of examples that are using `NSDictionary` with Swift.
**What's the difference between these two?**
I want to use an array with index in Swift like an array in PHP.
**Which one is better to use?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Dictionary is a native Swift struct. NSDictionary is a Cocoa class. They are bridged to one another (within the usual limits), as the docs explain very clearly and fully.

It's exactly parallel to Array and NSArray.

Comment: so Dictionary + NSDictionary is the same? but i see there are two ways to declare it. So i confused.

Comment: They're "the same" insofar as the runtime will convert between the two.

Comment: Actually, `Dictionary` is a struct, not a class.

Comment: I would also add that NSDictionary is a reference type where as Dictionary, like every struct in Swift, is a value type.

Comment: So how to choose?

Comment: @Alston If you are writing Swift code, use a Dictionary, the Swift type. If you are writing (or talking to) Objective-C code, use (or cast to) NSDictionary.

Comment: Is it just a compile-time cast or is there something going on at runtime?

Answer (score 7):

In practice and with regard to Swift's strong type concept the significant  difference is

- `NSDictionary` is generally type unspecified
- `Dictionary` is supposed to have a specific type.

Hence native `Dictionary` is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the deal,

For all intents and purposes, they are the same thing. So long as you import `Foundation`, the compiler will know them as the same thing.

As for specific differences, [thus Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) helps.

> Overview

`NSObject` is the root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies. Through `NSObject`, objects inherit a basic interface to the runtime system and the ability to behave as Objective-C objects.

What that means, in a nutshell, is that `NSObjects` are ancient relics from olden (objective c) times.

As for what is better, that is up to you. I find swift objects better than the ns counterpart just for the purpose of keeping code modern, however you may have to use ns objects if you are using code like `NSURLCONNECTION` that requires ns objects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are they though?  Swift dictionaries are pass by value, whereas NSDictionaries are pass by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example

```
    let dataArray = NSMutableArray()

    let d0 = ["code":"AA","name":"American Airlines"]
    let d1 = ["code":"BA","name":"British Airlines"]
    let d2 = ["code":"DA","name":"Delta Airlines"]

    dataArray.addObject(d0)
    dataArray.addObject(d1)
    dataArray.addObject(d2)
```

later...

```
let d0 = dataArray.objectAtIndex(0) as! [String:String]
let lbl = UILabel() 
lbl.text = d0["code"] // no xcode warnings
```

Using NSDictionary in swift

```
let d0 = dataArray.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
```

Now you need to coerce the dictionary value into shape.

```
lbl1.text = d0["name"] as! String
```

From experience - when dealing with json responses - I've used NSDictionary as it's loosely typed and I can't guaranteed to know exactly what it contains - just that is valid json. There's a growing library of native swift tools to handle this use case, I suggest looking here
https://github.com/search?q=json+NSDictionary+swift&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

In this case - you need to hack around data with the 'if let' dance.

```
if let results = json["result"] as? NSDictionary
```

lastly - NSMutableDictionary is more on par with Dictionary as you won't be able to mutate the key / value pairs on a NSDictionary.

eg.

```
results["code"] = 100 // <-- BOOM
```

the work around -

```
let mResults = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary:results)

mResults["code"] = NSNumber(100) // <-- OK
```

which begs the clarification - you can only stick NSObjects (NSNumbers / NSArrays / NSCount/NSSet) inside the NSMutableDictionaries. The Swift Dictionary gets around this.