# NSClasses vs Swift new classes

Tags: xcode, swift, variables, ios7, xcode6

I have been reading apple documentation and I couldn't find an answer for this questions.

In the new variables we create in Swift should we be using some of the old NSClasses (like NSDictionary) or should we use the new Swift classes (like Dictionary).

I am trying to keep consistent in use Swift classes everywhere I can but is there any difference in between the two (in this case NSDictionary and Dictionary) 
Did anyone find something about this topic in the apple documentation?

This is not a duplicate of "What is difference between NSDictionary vs Dictionary in Swift?"

I know the differences and I know that one has the root class NSObject and another has the root class AnyObject. Reformulating my question I want to know how that affect me as a developer? Did anyone did a benchmark? Is it fast slower? Is apple planning to make the NSClasses obsolete in the future? And I am not limiting this discussion to NSDictionary but to the whole new variables in swift that substitute the variables pre existents in Object-C

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is difference between NSDictionary vs Dictionary in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554259/what-is-difference-between-nsdictionary-vs-dictionary-in-swift)

Comment: AnyObject is a protocol, not a class.

Comment: @Amit89 so string does not have an root class?

Comment: Because anyObject can represent any class type my understand was that it is the root class in swift, would you mind to share your knowledge or font of information with us @Amit89 I would be very interested in understand the differences.

Comment: @IcaroNZ `String` is a struct, not a class and thus cannot inherit from another struct or any other type, so no, it does not have a root class. http://i.imgur.com/bndgvDg.png

Comment: As per documentation, structures can not be inherited, but they can confirm to protocols. Even if you create string in Swift it will be converted to NSString by the compiler, with the help of code interoperability of Swift. Data types that are convertible or can be used interchangeably are referred to as bridged data types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift classes provide type safety which means you assume less while working with objects inside collections. So it always better to use Swift variants than Objective-C wherever possible.